# How to correctly format measured time (in minutes and seconds with optional hours) in Excel?

Tags: excel

All I want is to enter time in an Excel sheet in the format [hh]:mm:ss without Excel going batsh*t crazy on me.

I just want to enter 30:25 as 30 minutes 25 seconds without it turning into 30:25:00 in the cell and somehow "1/1/1900  6:25:00 AM" in the formula bar.

If it's one colon it's just minutes and seconds, if there's two colons it also includes hours. Is this not possible at all?

Comment: When I format the cell as "hh:mm:ss" it works for hours and minutes + optional seconds just fine!? Only when I type hours only (like 10), it formats it as a full date for whatever reason.

Comment: AFAIK Excel always interprets something like 30:25 as hours and minutes (so you get a date as it's more than one day). The only options I can think of are to enter it in full 00:30:25 or enter it as text and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Application.StatusBar = Minute(Now) & " minutes " & Second(Now) & " seconds."    
End Sub
```

If you have some kind of OCD and you like to have minutes and minute, depending on whether it is 1 minute or not, this is a way to achieve it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim currentTime     As Date
    Dim displayValue    As String

    currentTime = Now

    If Minute(currentTime) = 1 Then
        displayValue = Minute(currentTime ) & " minute "
    Else
        displayValue = Minute(currentTime ) & " minutes "
    End If

    If Second(currentTime) = 1 Then
        displayValue = displayValue & Second(currentTime) & " second."
    Else
        displayValue = displayValue & Second(currentTime) & " seconds."
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = displayValue

End Sub
```

[This is a reference for the Minute Function for VB.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eayd8ts(v=vs.90).aspx)